# ForkJoinPool scheduling vs ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I'm slightly confused by the internal scheduling mechanism of the `ExecutorService` and the `ForkJoinPool`.

I understand the `ExecutorService` scheduling is done [this way](https://www.callicoder.com/assets/images/post/large/executor-service-thread-pool-blocking-queue-example.jpg).

A bunch of tasks are queued. Once a thread is available it will handle the first available task and so forth.

Meanwhile, a `ForkJoinPool` is presented as distinct because it uses a **work-stealing algorithm**. If I understand correctly it means a thread can steal some tasks from another thread.

Yet, I don't really understand the difference between the mechanism implemented in `ExecutorService` and in `ForkJoinPool`. From my understanding, both mechanisms should reduce the idle time of each thread as much as possible.

I would understand if in the case of an `ExecutorService`, each thread would have its own queue. Yet, it is not the case as the queue is shared by the different threads of the pool...

Any clarification would be more than welcome!

Comment: an `ExecutorService` has a single queue, so if you have 20 tasks and 5 threads, each of these threads will process those tasks; if on the other hand these 20 tasks can be divided in smaller ones, ForkJoinPool will most probably will be faster, since there are multiple queues for it - one initial and one for each thread- thus enabling work stealing as such

Comment: Let's say I'm using a `parallelStream()`, does it mean that one task represent a list of operations (like one `map` and one `filter`)? Thus, if two threads are available and that it remains one task to execute, it can be split into two subtasks meaning that one thread will perform the `map` and another one will perform the `filter`? I'd like to concretely illustrate your answer :)

Comment: no no, a certain thread executes the entire pipeline; once you use `parallelStream` the entire source of the stream will be split in chunks and those chunks are processed by ForkJoinPool threads; if a certain thread is "free", it can go to some other threads queue, take some chunks from it and start processing it (by splitting it even in smaller chunks of work)

Comment: I don't undertand why this mechanism would be more interesting than having a shared queue like an `ExecutorService`.. Would you have a concrete example of work stealing in case of a `parallelStrem` please? Something that would illustrate where we can be better than using an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: I thought adding an answer instead of a really long comment(s), tell me if that makes more sense now

Comment: That makes sense. I still have some questions but I have to experiment stuff. Yet, it gives me a great overview. Thanks!

Comment: *I would understand if in the case of an ExecutorService, each thread would have its own queue. Yet, it is not the case as the queue is shared by the different threads of the pool...*, I don't quite understand, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose you have a very big array of ints and you want to add all of them. With an `ExecutorService` you might say: let's divide that array into chunks of let's say number of threads / 4. So if you have an array of 160 elements (and you have 4 CPUs), you create `160 / 4 / 4 = 10`, so you would create 16 chunks each holding 10 ints. Create runnables/callables and submit those to an executor service (and of course think of a way to merge those results once they are done).

Now your hopes are that each of the CPUs will take 4 of those tasks and work on them. Now let's also suppose that some of the numbers are very complicated to add (of course not, but bear with me), it could turn out that 3 threads/CPUs are done with their work while one of them is busy only with the first chunk. No one wants that, of course, but could happen. The bad thing now is that you can't do anything about it.

What `ForkJoinPool` does instead is say provide me with how you want to split your task and the implementation for the minimal workload I have to do and I'll take care of the rest. In the `Stream API` this is done with `Spliterator`s; mainly with two methods `trySplit` (that either returns `null` meaning nothing can be split more or a new `Spliterator` - meaning a new chunk) and `forEachRemaning` that will process elements once you can't split your task anymore. And this is where work stealing will help you.

You say *how* your chunks are computed (usually split in half) and what to do when you can't split anymore. `ForkJoinPool` will dispatch the first chunk to all threads and when some of them are free - they are done with their work, they can query other queues from other threads and see if they have work. If they notice that there are chunks in some other threads queues, they will take them, split them on their own and work on those. It can even turn out that they don't do the entire work on that chunks on their own - some other thread can now query this thread's queue and notice that there is still work to do and so on... This is far better as now, when those 3 threads are free they can pick up some other work to do - and all of them are busy.

---

This example is a bit simplified, but is not very far from reality. It's just that you need to have a lot more chunks than CPU's/threads for work stealing to work; thus usually `trySplit` has to have a smart implementation and you need lots of elements in the source of your stream.