# Fork-Join Pool in parallel streams

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

I had searched through various articles online and Stack Overflow questions but I am not able to find the perfect answer for this. Many questions are there which are close to this, but are slightly different.

> We know Java 8 Streams API uses Fork-Join Pool internally.

Now my question is how the tasks in stream pipeline is divided using Fork-Join pool?

Suppose we have the following:

```
List myList =  inputList.parallelStream().filter( x -> x>0 )
    .map(x -> x+100 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now we have two options for dividing the tasks using thread pools.

1. Take `filter` and `map` as a single task and run it using fork-join pool.
2. Take `filter` and `map` as a two different tasks and run these using two different fork-join thread-pools.

Also I know that stream are lazily propagated so if we have a  **stateful intermediate operation**  in between as:

```
List myList2 = inputList.parallelStream().filter( x -> x>0 )
    .map(x -> x+5 ).sorted().map(x -> x+5 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then how will the thread-pools be created?

PS: I know the map function can be combined before. I just wanted to make an example for the question.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The Java Stream API can use Fork-Join Pool, however that require you to use `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`. By default the streaming API just uses the current thread.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the info. I have used parallel stream now and saw that with `stream()`, `main thread ` is used and with `parallelStream()` , fork-join is used. But how is Fork-Join tasks created? Still thinking about that, as `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker ` threads are used everywhere.

Comment: you could accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: @Eugene, The explanation is not good.Can you edit the answer. Anyone will need to read it thrice to understand.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you *have* to use `parallel` for the `Fork-Join Pool` to be active. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717900/forkjoinpool-scheduling-vs-executorservice/52729788#52729788) explains a bit what `Spliterator`s are how the splitting is performed; but in simple words splitting is done using the source of stream elements and *an entire pipeline* is processed in parallel. In your example it's `filter` *and* `map` as you put it (of course it includes the `terminal` operation also).

For stateful operations - things are more complicated. Let's take `distinct` for example and first see how it handles things for the sequential case.

In general you could think that a `non-parallel` `distinct` could be implemented using `HashSet` - and you would be correct. `HashSet` could hold all the values that have been already *seen* and simply not process (send to the next operations) the other elements - and theoretically you would be done with a non parallel `distinct` operation.  But what if the `Stream` is known to be `SORTED`? Think about it, it means that we could keep a single element (as opposed to a `HashSet` as before) that would be marked as `seen`. Basically if you would have:

```
 1,1,2,2,3
```

it would mean that your *stateful* operation could be implemented on top of a single element - not a `HashSet`; the code would be something like:

```
T seen = null;
....
if(seen == null || (!currentElement.equals(seen)){
    seen = currentElement;
    // process seen;
}
```

But this optimization is only possible when you know that the stream is `SORTED`, since this way you know that the next element coming is either the same as the one you have already seen or a new one, that is impossible for you to have seen before in some other previous operation - this is guaranteed by a sort operation.

And now how is a `parallel distinct` implemented. You basically ask this question:

> Then how will the thread-pools be created

The same way, nothing changes from a Stream perspective, `ForkJoinPool` uses the same number of threads - the only thing that changes is the stream implementation, obviously.

In simple words, if your `Stream` is `ORDERED` the internal implementation uses a `LinkedHashSet` (actually multiple instances of this, since it really does a reduction in such a case) to preserve your order and it uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` if you don't care about order - that is either if the source is not ordered (like a `Set`) or you used explicit called `unordered`. You can look up the implementation for `sorted` too, if you really want to know how it's done.

---

So the bottom line is that a `Fork Join Pool` does not change the implementation based on the stream, it uses the same model. On the other hand based on the operations that you have, the Stream API might use some stateful data for stateful intermediate operations, be that a `HashSet/ConcurrentHashMap`, or a single element, etc.

Comment: Hi @Eugene , Thanks you for your detailed answer. I need to look into `Spliterators` and some other concepts. So it might take some time to discuss or decide further.

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal you could accept the answer btw, 3 years after :)